# stop and restart function with setTimeout() method with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created a function that picks colors from an array to change the background color. After being visited, picking from array will restart. Then I added two buttons in `<body>` element to stop and restart the color picking, I want the function to continue picking color by the point I pressed the "stop" button when I select the "restart" button.
I tried this way but it restarts from the first element of the array:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    const colors = ['blue','red','yellow','green'];
    let loop;
    function start(i){
      if(i < colors.length){
        loop = setTimeout(function(){
          $('body').css("backgroundColor", colors[i]);
          i++;
          if (i >= colors.length) {
            i = 0;
          }
          start(i);
        }, 1000);
      }
    }

    $('#btnStop').on('click', () => {
      clearTimeout(loop);
    });

    $('#btnRestart').on('click', () => {
      loop = start(0);
    });

    start(0);
  })
```

Comment: `loop = start(0)` is wrong, you should not be setting it to start.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use an interval instead of a timeout?

Comment: @CodeSpent it is perfectly fine to not use an interval.

Comment: *"but it restarts from the first element"* - because of the `start(0)` says: start from the first element.   You need to record/store the position *outside* of the `setTimeout` (one way would be to move `i` to same position as `loop`, but I'd use a different name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by adding another variable

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    const colors = ['blue','red','yellow','green'];
    let loop;
    var iNUM = 0; //<<<<<<<<<<<
    function start(i){
      if(i < colors.length){
        loop = setTimeout(function(){
          $('body').css("backgroundColor", colors[i]);
          i++;
          if (i >= colors.length) {
            i = 0;
          }
          iNUM = i; //<<<<<<<<<<
          start(i);
        }, 1000);
      }
    }

    $('#btnStop').on('click', () => {
      clearTimeout(loop);
    });

    $('#btnRestart').on('click', () => {
      start(iNUM); //<<<<<<<
    });

    start(0);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnStop">Stop</button>
<button id="btnRestart">Start</button>
```

Comment: In which case you don't need `i`

Answer (score 0):

How about `Array.shift()` and `Array.push()`?

```js
const colors = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green'];
console.log(colors[0]);
colors.push(colors.shift());
console.log(colors[0]);
```